# Race condition with webhooks when updating a Stripe Connect account and my db, that cannot be resolved with concurrency exception

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, webhooks, race-condition, optimistic-concurrency

**Scenario** - I'm updating a Stripe Connect(bank) account, that has a payout status of disabled, by providing it with an additional identifying document for verification. This will enable the payout status, so that the user can receive payouts. When Stripe receives the document from my server it sends 2 "account.updated" webhooks that I read and save the data from in my db. One of these two webhooks has the updated payout enabled status of true, the other webhook has a payout status of false.

**PROBLEM1** -  There is no guarantee that I receive the webhooks in the order in which they are sent. [Stripe order of events](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#event-ordering) So in some cases I might receive the event updated webhook with the disabled payout status 1st and the event updated webhook with the enabled payout status 2nd.

**PROBLEM2** - Even if I receive the webhooks in order (payouts disabled 1st, payouts enabled 2nd) my server might process them at different times (depending on load) and save them out of order from the order with which I received them. Once again leaving my user seeing a disabled account, even when it's enabled.

**FYI** - From what I can see from my testing so far, Stripe always seems to generate and send the account updated webhook in the correct order (disabled 1st, enabled 2nd). Here are 2 examples.

**EXAMPLE 1** - From Stripe dashboard, notice the timestamp difference

[image]

> Event: evt_1JfsTQQaRtdb8QPYdufePsBa => "payouts_enabled": true

> Event: evt_1JfsTQQaRtdb8QPYdh17AreO => "payouts_enabled": false

**EXAMPLE 2** - From Stripe dashboard, notice the timestamp is the **same**

[image]

> Event: evt_1JgaR7QgKzBv3Rh9Dx6Xq3W9 => "payouts_enabled": true

> Event: evt_1JgaR7QgKzBv3Rh996DT3gBC => "payouts_enabled": false

**GOAL** - Making sure that the most current account info is updated on my side from the webhooks that I receive from Stripe, regardless of the order with which they are processed or received. So that I don't end up with an account payout status of disabled to display to the user, when the payout status is true.

**What I've tried** - Solving problem 1 and 2 above seemed simple enough. I implemented optomistic concurrency using a DbUpdateConcurrencyException, where I looked at the time stamp (stripeEvent.Created) of the Stripe event and only updated my DB when the concurrency exception is thrown **and** if the Stripe event timestamp I receive is later than what's in the current table row column "EventCreatedDate".

ex.

```
    [HttpPost("stripe")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> StripeWebhook()
    {
        var json = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

        try
        {
            Event stripeEvent = EventUtility.ConstructEvent(json, Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"], WhSecret);

            // Handle the events
            if (stripeEvent.Type == Events.AccountUpdated)
            {
                var stripeAccount = stripeEvent.Data.Object as Stripe.Account;
                var spec = new StripeAccountWithTypeSpecification(stripeAccount.Id);
                var dbEntity = await _unitOfWork.Repository<StripeAccount>().GetEntityWithSpec(spec);
                if (dbEntity == null) 
                    return BadRequest();
                // only update the db row if the Stripe account created timestamp is the same or later than what he have in the DB (EventCreatedDate)
                if (dbEntity.EventCreatedDate.CompareTo(stripeAccount.Created) <= 0) {
                    _mapper.Map(stripeAccount, dbEntity);
                    dbEntity.EventCreatedDate = stripeEvent.Created;
                    _unitOfWork.Repository<StripeAccount>().Update(dbEntity);
                    try
                    {
                        var success = await _unitOfWork.Complete();
                    }
                    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
                    {
                        // Get the current entity values we are saving and the values in the database
                        var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
                        var currentValues = entry.CurrentValues;
                        var entityDate = currentValues.GetValue<DateTime>("EventCreatedDate");
                        
                        var databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues();
                        var databaseDate = databaseValues.GetValue<DateTime>("EventCreatedDate");

                        // If the Stripe created datetime timestamp (EventCreatedDate) in the database is in the past or equal to the timestamp we are trying to insert then we insert it.
                        // This will ensure only the most recently sent events get updated in the DB, if we experienced a concurrency exception
                        if (databaseDate.CompareTo(entityDate) <= 0) {
                            // Update the values of the entity that failed to save from the store
                            ex.Entries.Single().Reload();
                        }
                        _logger.LogInformation("Concurrency Exception Thrown");
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (stripeEvent.Type == Events.AccountApplicationDeauthorized)
            {
                var application = stripeEvent.Data.Object as Stripe.Application;
                _logger.LogInformation("Account application deauthorized id: {0}: ", application.Id);
            }
            else
            {
                // Unexpected event type
                _logger.LogInformation("Unhandled event type: {0}", stripeEvent.Type);
            }
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (StripeException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Stripe Exception: {0}, {1}", ex.Message, ex);
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

**PROBLEM WITH MY SOLUTION** - The problem is that if you look at the Stripe dashboard event timestamps shown from example 2, they're the same! So I could end up with a scenario where I process the disabled payout webhook 2nd and because it has the same timestamp as the webhook event with a payout status of enabled. It will overwrite the payout status true event, leaving me with a payout status of disabled!!! So I can't rely or use the Stripe event timestamp to check which events are sent first.

**QUESTION** - I'm currently looking to see if there are "Stripe.Event" properties that can be used to determine the most current event sent to me. Does anyone have any advice for me on what I can do here?

Comment: The best option is to retrieve the current Account object from the API and sync your system with that returned response, not the actual event body(since as you say, it might be out of date). It's better to treat the event as a notification that 'something happened' and trigger a process to grab the current Account state from the API and sync with that.

Comment: Ya, not sure about that...I am "syncing" with the account object and saving properties from it into my DB every time I get an account updated webhook. With my site, my users can have multiple connect accounts (displayed on a single page), so fetching all their accounts when they traverse to that page, might be a little laborious/time consuming/etc? Not just because I'm fetching multiple accounts, but also because I'm saving the data as well, just to display account data on their account page.

Comment: I don't think it would overly time-consuming, a retrieve API request can be pretty fast. Ultimately I don't have a better idea for you so maybe these are just the constraints you have to build your system within!

Comment: Hi Karl. FYI the user might have 10 accounts which would mean 10 API requests, not 1. While 1 might not be that slow, having 5, 8, 9, 10, would most likely affect the flow in a profound way. Not just because of the time it takes to fetch, but then I also have to save the data for each fetch. Saving the data could be spawned in a separate thread via a service or something, but it would still be a lot of processing just to display account info on the screen for the user each time they user traverses to his/her accounts page.

Comment: It's a little old but I still wanted to chime in as I think you're misunderstanding @karllekko, the idea is not that you fetch the connect accounts every time a user on your platform visits their dashboard, just when stripe sends you an event you don't look at the event data itself, but just use it as a signal to fetch the account object from sripe and use this to store whatever info you need, this way you should get the fresh state

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this concurrency issue for a while too. The only difference is that it affected subscriptions, but the logic is the exact same.
In the end, here's what I did :

I left my original logic that handles every incoming event right away. Most of the time, there are no race conditions. This way, it provides instant feedback in our database for almost every customer.

On top of that, I now use our queue to start a job which will make sure the subscription is properly synced. It's a very simple implementation where I delay a SyncStripeSubscription job by one minute. Its only job data is the stripe subscription id. It then fetches the stripe subscription, which has supposedly been properly updated on Stripe's end after this little delay, and updates the database accordingly just in case the race condition happened.

While a bit more convoluted, this logic ensures that, at the very worst, our database will be properly synced after one minute.